# Getting local variables using javassist?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist

Is there any way of getting the names of local variables using javassist ? My final aim is to get the Objects hashcode at run time. For example if I have a code snippet like:

```
void try(){
Integer a = 123;
System.out.println(a);
}
```

I would like to instrument it so that it looks like something like:

```
void try(){
Integer a = 123;
System.out.println(a.hashCode());
System.out.println(a);
}
```

So, I am trying to get the local variable name 'a' and then instrumenting that back in the code. Is there any of getting the name and also, is there any better way of doing the same thing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name `a` of the local variable is only meta information. At runtime, this information is index-dependent. For a non-static method, the local variables would be stored in an array containing the references:

```
------------
|  0   | 1 |
------------
| this | a |
------------
```

Accessing `a` is performed by performing the `ALOAD_1` instruction. What you need to do is to parse the byte code for such an instruction and to repeat it, calling the hash code method it and print it.

Comment: As a side note, you can’t rely on this mapping. The only thing which is fixed is that `this` maps to variable `0` at the beginning of the method. A compiler may use index `1` for `a` but it may also use a bigger index, having unused indices between `this` and `a` (but that’s rather unusual), but it may also use index `0` for `a` as `this` is not used in the subsequent code…